# Woocommerce Custom Rewrite Rules Array - Subcategories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rewrite-rules

Using this code here:

```
    add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'services/([^/]*?)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'services/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
} );
```

and having these permalink settings

product category base:  services

product permalink - custom base:  /services/%product_cat%

I get the following:

/services/%category_name%/  (Parent Product Category Page works fine)

/services/%category_name%/%subcategory_name/ (***Child Product Category Page does not work - gets 404***)

/services/%category_name%/%subcategory_name/%product_name (Single Products - works fine)

Anybody have any insight on how to get the Child Product Category pages to not throw the 404 error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'services/([^/]*?)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'services/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
        'services/([^/]*?)/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[2]'
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
} );
```

Comment: Please, explain what the code does and how it answers the quesiton. Just dumpling code is not a good answer.